# Cannot show Togglz using a JDBCStateRepository in Spring Boot environment

Tags: spring-boot, togglz

In a Spring Boot 2.1 environment, I would like to use Togglz that are stored in a JDBCStateRepository.

The problem is: **The Togglz are not shown in the console. The Togglz are not stored in the database.**

My setup happens via the following files:

**Maven**:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.togglz</groupId>
  <artifactId>togglz-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.togglz</groupId>
  <artifactId>togglz-console</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

**FeatureOptions**:

```
public enum FeatureOptions implements Feature {
    @EnabledByDefault
    @Label("Zwerfobjecten geheel draaien in volgende snapshot")
    FEATURE_ONE;
    public boolean isActive() {
        return FeatureContext.getFeatureManager().isActive(this);
    }
}
```

**TogglzConfiguration**:

```
@Configuration
public class TogglzConfiguration implements TogglzConfig {
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    public Class<? extends Feature> getFeatureClass() {
        return FeatureOptions.class;
    }

    @Bean
    public StateRepository getStateRepository() {
        return new JDBCStateRepository(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public UserProvider getUserProvider() {
        return new NoOpUserProvider();
    }

    @Bean
    public FeatureProvider featureProvider() {
        return new EnumBasedFeatureProvider(FeatureOptions.class);
    }
}
```

The **application.properties** are:

```
togglz.feature-enums=nl.xyz.project.togglz.FeatureOptions
togglz.console.path=/togglz-console
togglz.console.enabled=true
togglz.console.secured=false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one property was missing ...

```
togglz.console.use-management-port=false
```